# Wordpress elementor - Listing grid slider - breakpoint bug

Tags: wordpress, slider, breakpoints, elementor, jet-engine

Not sure why that happend - even having my breakpoints on 1024/1025 (tablet/desktop) - listing grid SLIDER(because only slider catches bug) breakpoint is 1014/1015 (tablet/desktop). First time this is happening to me and I'm confused - anyone had that problem before and knows what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and maybe for someone in future it will be usefull.

Problem was horizontal gap bettwen each slide on tablet - it takes default value from desktop (if I don't change it) and it was for some reason too big in my case. I had 40px gap bettwen slides on desktop. I changed it on tablet to 20px since it took desktop value by default(40px). Reducing that gap on tablet fixed my problem with breakpoint [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fig5i.png)